# Model specification

Tags: regression

Actually I want to see the impact of Investors sentiment on Aggregate stock market return, so my major concern is to identify the impact of investors sentiment.

But besides investors sentiment I want to include 5 more Independent variable which might have impact also stock market return.

Its a single STOCK MARKET analysis (USA), here N=1

So can anybody suggests me what model I can use to test it other than Multiple Regression Analysis?

Comment: Hi, James, and welcome to Cross Validated! Is there a particularly reason you don't want to use regression? It's a fairly large family containing some very powerful tools....

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have so many variables, you can try brute force search to select the best variables that influence your outcome most. Refer [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79366/maximum-number-of-independent-variables-in-logistic-regression/79541#79541) for more details.